# Are there any examples/instructions on how to use AWS S3 with CKFinder?

Tags: amazon-s3, ckfinder

I want to use AWS's S3 service to host files and images for my site, but I also want to use CKEditor & CKFinder for the editor.  Are there any examples of integrating AWS & CKFinder?

Comment: Nope, I'm having to upload to a local server 1st then have it use the AWS API to upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a Windows-based solution there are a few products available that will allow you to map a drive to an S3 bucket. We use a product called TnTDrive for this purpose. (Note that we are in no way affiliated with the creators of this product) File uploads via CKEditor will pass through the mapped drive whereas client browsers will download those files directly from S3. No matter which product you use the config is straightforward:

1. Create the drive mapping
2. Add a read-only policy to the bucket
3. Change the `config.baseUrl` and `config.baseDir` parameters in your
   CKFinder config file to point to the bucket and new drive.

Hope this proves useful.

Comment: This is a decent solution, I was hoping for a plugin for CKFinder/Editor that would use the S3 API, but it seems I was shooting for the moon with that one

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a similar situation, and despite both CKEditor/CKFinder and S3 being popular, the web still hasn't provided a good solution that I can find. The best lead I've found is [this comment on a corefive blog post](http://labs.corefive.com/2009/10/30/an-open-file-manager-for-ckeditor-3-0/#comment-1821) where someone claims to have written one using codeigniter.

If you do find or create a solution for this, please post it here!

Comment: I contacted the author and here is a link to the [github repository](https://github.com/jzumbrun/Filemanager) for that comment. It doesn't seem very clean. The controller is a mess and the library quite tangled up in CodeIgniter. I might take a crack at this problem and post a response if I'm successful.

Answer (score -1):

follow link https://github.com/colonelchlorine/ckfinder-amazon-s3 and https://github.com/colonelchlorine/ckfinder-amazon-s3/issues/7. this code is very useful who looking for editor, finder and aws s3 all to gather.
Hope it helps someone.